# SwiftUI: Force use of dark material regardless of color scheme

Tags: ios, macos, swiftui

Is it possible to force the use of the dark or light material in SwiftUI regardless of the current color scheme? Using `.preferredColorScheme` will apply the color scheme to the entire view and not only the material. The reason is that I'm using an `AVPlayer` and I need to overlay additional UI that should match the appearance of the player's UI, which seems to always use dark material.

The only work-around I am aware of, is implementing an `UIBlurEffect` through an `UIViewRepresentable`, e.g. with this package: https://github.com/twostraws/VisualEffects

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Use this as your background modifier:

```
.background {
    Color.clear
        .background(.ultraThinMaterial)
        .environment(\.colorScheme, .dark)
}
```

Comment: This is a great solution for preventing to spread the scheme to other views.